# In wordpress add_action how can I pass $priority $accepted_args when using a class

Tags: wordpress, class, oop, plugins

I have this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_checkboxes', 'pm_form_field_modify', 10, 4 );

function pm_form_field_modify( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    ob_start();
    pm_print_list_field( $key, $args, $value );
    $field = ob_get_clean();

    if ( $args['return'] ) {
        return $field;
    } else {
        echo $field;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to write it as a class. I have a class format that has a function that is run when it is instansiated but when I am writing the:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_checkboxes', array( $this,'pm_form_field_modify' ));
```

I cannot pass the $priority and $accepted_args as the array expects exactly 2 paramaters. How can I pass these to my public function class as i need to specify 4 paramaters for the function.

I have checked [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) but found the doucmentation lacking when it comes to using classes and OOP.

Comment: Do you mean to say that how can $priority and $accepted_args need to pass in class based add_filter that you mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_checkboxes', array( $this,'pm_form_field_modify' ), 10, 4);
```

Comment: Silly me, this answer is correct, the second parameter when using a class expects an array of only 2 fields. $this (the class) and the function. I was placing the ,10,4 inside the array where it should have been outside like the answer given here.